# angular ui jQuery Passthrough for resizable jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

i have been trying to use angular ui jQuery Passthrough for jquery resizable plugin

```
adocsModule.value('uiJqConfig', {   
    resizable: {
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            alert('stop');
        }
    }
});
```

now when i call it on div

```
<div style="height: 30px; width:60px; border:solid; padding:2px" 
            ng-repeat="item in list2" ui-jq="resizable"  >
```

it works fine div get resized but problem is i want to hook stop function in controller

like they say that use ui-options to do it . can some one guide me how can i move this method to controller rather to have in configuration ??

or this is not possible with jquery passthrough ? or any angular directive which can do resizing and have callback functions

any help will be appreciated

**Update:**

i have made some changes and now its something like this

```
$scope.stopCallBack = function (event, ui, item) {
        alert('stop');
    }

    $scope.startCallBack = function (event, ui, item) {
        alert('start');
    }


    $scope.optionsObj = {
        start:$scope.startCallBack,
        stop: $scope.stopCallBack
    };


<div style="height: 30px; width:60px; border:solid; padding:2px" 
                ng-repeat="item in list2" ui-jq="resizable" ui-options="startCallBack,stopCallBack,optionsObj"  >
```

is this a right way of doing it and secondly how to pass parameter to these functions . reason is i wanted to know which element is getting resized

for example if i do this i get error

```
ui-options="startCallBack(item, $index),stopCallBack,optionsObj"
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

ui-options="{start:startCallBack},{stop:stopCallBack}"